# How to find the unknown values in this Numerical Integration type?

Tags: functional-analysis, integration, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Given the following type of numerical integration:

$$I(f)=\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx  \approx  \frac 12 f(x_{0}) +c_1 f(x_1) $$

a) Find the values ​​of: the coefficient $c_1$ and points $x_0$ and $x_1$ so that the above formula numerical integration to be as accurate as possible.

b)Find the error of the formula of the numerical integration in (a).

c)What is the degree of accuracy of the numerical integration formula in (a)?

Comment: It's usually better not to phrase your questions here in the kind of language that's appropriate for an instructor to use in assigning a problem.  It can make people suspect that you're stenographically passing on to us a question written by someone else that you might not even understand, rather than asking your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to interpret "as accurate as possible." One common interpretation is that it is dead on for $f(x)$ identically equal to $1$, for $f(x)=x$, for $f(x)=x^2$, and so on for as long as possible.

If the formula is to give the right answer for $f(x)=1$ (and hence for $f(x)$ any constant function) we need $c_1=\frac{1}{2}$.

For the formula to give the right answer for $f(x)=x$, we then need 
$\frac{1}{2}(x_0+x_1)=\int_0^1 x\,dx=\frac{1}{2}$. So we need $x_0+x_1=1$.

For the formula to give the right answer for $f(x)=x^2$, we  need 
$\frac{1}{2}(x_0^2+x_1^2)=\int_0^1 x^2\,dx=\frac{1}{3}$. So we need $x_0^2+x_1^2=\frac{2}{3}$.

Solve the equations $x_0+x_1=1$, $x_0^2+x_1^2=\frac{2}{3}$  for $x_0$ and $x_1$. We get $x_0=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$ and $x_1=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$.

**Remarks:** $1.$ This little problem connects with important mathematics. For detail, look for **Gaussian quadrature**. It turns out that by choosing suitable **not** uniformly distributed points, and suitable weights, one can produce numerical integration procedures that are extremely efficient. This is particularly important in situations where function evaluation is "expensive."

$2.$ We did not **try** to get the right answer for $x^3$, since obviously $x_0$ and $x_1$ were determined when we dealt with $x^2$. However, we get a nice bonus! It turns out the formula is **exact** for $x^3$. This is not hard to show, all we need to do is to verify that $\frac{1}{2}(x_0^3+x_1^3)=\frac{1}{4}$. That is a short calculation.

So the formula gives dead on right answers for $1$, $x$, $x^2$, and $x^3$. Thus, by linearity the formula  is dead on for all polynomials of degree $\le 3$.

Comment: very nice answer ..... :)

Comment: I have to find the solution using the theory of numerical integration such as Trapezium rule, Simpson's rule, rule 3/8 etc. Which method follows your method above? (I'm sorry if my question is "stupid" but i am not enough familiar with this theory..)

Comment: I mention it in the answer. **Gaussian quadrature** is the general technique. I think there is a Wikipedia article. I imagine a search will give many hits.

Comment: Thank you very much, i found the theory an understood your answer! Could you please help me with (b), (c) questions too?

Comment: I had not seen those. Have they been added? It is not possible to give a reasonable answer to them without heavy assumptions about the function. One **could** assume that the fourth derivative is bounded by $B$. Then we can find the error $E$ on $x^4$ by direct calculation, and conclude that the error is $\lt \frac{BE}{4!}$.

Comment: Thanks again.Yes, i added them before. I have to find the fourth derivative of what? Could you please be more analytical to help me more to understand your answer about (b)?

Comment: You have to have bounds on the fourth derivative of the function $f*x)$ you are doing a numerical integration on. Since no information is supplied about $f(x)$, there is nothing explicit we can do. For the estimate, **if** given such information, one would use some estimate for the remainder when the Taylor polynomial of degree $3$ is used to approximate $f(x)$, probably the Lagrange form of the remainder. The estimate would be no good for a function like $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: So, given this information, we can't answer exactly the (b)?

Comment: I just realized that for (c) probably all they want is that the formula is exact or all polynomials of degree $\le 3$, which was already part of my answer.